# Including a complex Matplotlib.Pytplot figure in Latex

Tags: pgfplots, python, includegraphics, matplotlib

I'm not sure if I should post this on the Python SE or here. I have made a complex figure in Python that is exactly how I want it to be. Now I want to include that figure in my thesis in LaTeX. As of now I am taking a screenshot of the figure and including it in LaTeX like so:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{pythonfigure.png}
    \caption{The most accurate (top) and least accurate (bottom) transposition pathways}
    \label{fig:pythonfigure.png}
\end{figure}
```

This makes the figure quite fuzzy and low quality:
[image]

**Is there a way to transfer the figure from Python to LaTeX and still keep the crispness in LaTeX?**

My Python code for the figure is as follows:

```
def mod_meas_subplots(x, y1, label_a, label1b, ax1_title, y2, label2b, ax2_title, y3, label3b, ax3_title, y4, label4b, ax4_title,  graph_xlabel, graph_ylabel, windowtitle):
"""This function plots a figure containing four subplots of modelled vs measured irradiance."""
fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2,2)  
fig.canvas.set_window_title(windowtitle)
ax1.scatter(x, y1, marker = 'o', label = label1b, alpha = 0.30)
ax1.plot(range(0,1100), range(0,1100), 'r', label = label_a)
ax1.set_ylabel(graph_ylabel)
ax1.set_title(ax1_title)
ax1.set(adjustable='box-forced', aspect='equal')
ax1.set_xlim(0,1100)
ax1.set_ylim(0,1100)
ax1.legend(loc = 2)
ax1.grid(True)

ax2.scatter(x, y2, marker = 'o', label = label2b, alpha = 0.30)
ax2.plot(range(0,1100), range(0,1100), 'r', label = label_a)
ax2.tick_params(axis = 'y', left = 'off', labelleft ='off')
ax2.set_title(ax2_title)
ax2.set(adjustable='box-forced', aspect='equal')
ax2.set_xlim(0,1100)
ax2.set_ylim(0,1100)
ax2.legend(loc = 2)
ax2.grid(True)

ax3.scatter(x, y3, marker = 'o', label = label3b, alpha = 0.30) 
ax3.plot(range(0,1100), range(0,1100), 'r', label = label_a)
ax3.set_xlabel(graph_xlabel)
ax3.set_ylabel(graph_ylabel)
ax3.set_title(ax3_title)
ax3.set(adjustable='box-forced', aspect='equal')
ax3.set_xlim(0,1100)
ax3.set_ylim(0,1100)
ax3.legend(loc = 2)
ax3.grid(True)

ax4.scatter(x, y4, marker = 'o', label = label4b, alpha = 0.30)
ax4.plot(range(0,1100), range(0,1100), 'r', label = label_a)
ax4.tick_params(axis = 'y', left = 'off', labelleft ='off')
ax4.set_xlabel(graph_xlabel)
ax4.set_title(ax4_title)
ax4.set(adjustable='box-forced', aspect='equal')
ax4.set_xlim(0,1100)
ax4.set_ylim(0,1100)
ax4.legend(loc = 2)
ax4.grid(True)

fig.tight_layout  
plt.show()
```

And then calling the graph function with the right parameters:

```
mod_meas_subplots(df.G_POA_S_15, POAdirint_11.poa_global, 'Ideal line','MAE = ' +str(round(MAE_POAdirint_11, 2)), 'DIRINT and Perez: Phoenix 1988', 
                   POAdirint_14.poa_global, 'MAE = ' +str(round(MAE_POAdirint_14, 2)), 'DIRINT and Perez: Albuquerque 1988',
                   POAerbs_14.poa_global, 'MAE = ' +str(round(MAE_POAerbs_14, 2)), 'Erbs and Perez: Albuquerque 1988',
                   POAerbs_13.poa_global, 'MAE = ' +str(round(MAE_POAerbs_13, 2)), 'Erbs and Perez: Ossage 1988',
                   'Measured POA irradiance ($W/m^2$)', 'Modelled POA irradiance ($W/m^2$)', 'POA models with lowest and highest MAE')
```

Comment: I think the "bad quality" originates form your export or is a viewer problem, because LaTeX isn't changing the resolution of your images besides rescaling as you have stated to the `includegraphics` options. But currently I don't see any hurdles to reproduce your image(s) using PGFPlots. As a starting point you could use `https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/355918/95441`. If you provide the data file of your points I guess there are some people who would also assist you in doing so.

Comment: Take a look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/426071/117050 and/or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/391078/117050

Comment: It took me the whole morning to figure out how it worked with my function in a different python script, but it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's more of a python problem than latex. Anyway... 
You can save the figures from the python code directly with
`fig.savefig('full_figure.png', dpi=500)`
you can increase the `dpi`, the higher the number the more the figure will be defined but it will also be heavier.
Then you can add your latex figure as you described above.

Comment: Don't use `full_figure.png`. Instead setup `matplotlib` to use pgf and latex as backend and save as `full_figure.pdf`. Highest quality, fastest inclusion.